# MiKTeX installs wrong version of biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, miktex, biber, windows

I am using the 64-bit version of MiKTeX on Windows 10.
Just to be sure I just did a fresh installation of it.

I just switched from using BibTeX to Biber and BibLaTeX.
But running Biber always runs into the following error:

```
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3.
This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.10) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
```

This seems fair, because the required BibLaTeX version is 3.7. But using the MiKTeX Updater I don't receive a newer version of BibLaTeX. I even wanted to update BibLaTeX manually out of desperation, but don't find the corresponding files.

How can I fix this? Should I manually downgrade the Biber-Version? That's currently the only solution I could get to work.

Comment: Often this comes down to having two copies of files installed: have you run the MiKTeX update in 'user' and 'admin' modes?

Comment: If you installed MikTeX for all users you will find 'MikTeX Update (Admin)' and 'MikTeX Update' (user mode) on your PC. You will have to run both updaters at least twice to make sure that all packages are really up to date. If you installed Biber as admin, but `biblatex` as user, only `biblatex` will be updated if you run 'MikTeX Update', to update Biber as well you need to run 'MikTeX Update (Admin)'. Of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864

Comment: Your problem is with biber not with biblatex. biber is too old, run the update manager (admin).

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to run both Updaters?

Comment: Any news here? Could you resolve your version conflict?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by an outdated Biber version. Updating MikTeX with both Update managers solves the issue.